# Firestore pricing for batched writes

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

We have a Firestore document which is essentially a map with multiple entries:

```
{
    "entries": {
        "1": {
            "value": "x",
        },
        "2": {
            "value": "y",
        },
        "3": {
            "value": "z",
        },
        "4": {
            "value": "t",
        },
    },
}
```

We now want to prune some entries from here, but while we are doing so, there may be more writes (entries added) that we don't want to lose accidentaly.

There seem to be two approaches:

1. Do a transaction. Read the whole document, decide what to prune, write the whole document back.

```js
// approach 1
firestore.transaction(t => {
  const doc = t.read(docRef)
  // prune entries
  const prunedDoc = prune(doc) 
  t.write(docRef, prunedDoc)
})
```

2. Do a batched write. Read the whole document, decide what to prune, then do a series of updates which delete individual entries as a batched write.

```js
// approach 2
const doc = firestore.read(docRef)

// decide what to prune

firestore.batch(b => {
  // for each entry to be pruned
  b.update(docRef, "entries.${index}", FieldValue.delete())
})
```

I am wondering which solution is better:

- From performance perspective.
- From pricing perspective. What happens if there are multiple updates to the same document from a single batched write? Will that be charged as multiple writes?

Comment: Why would you do a series of writes? In either of these cases you're updating a single document atomically, so you should do a single write. Putting them in a batch or transaction does not seem to gain you anything.

Comment: I might be missing some nuance of your use-case here, which is why I'd highly recommend including the [minimal, illustrative code that shows what you're doing](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and what putting them into the batch/transaction partially through that process gains you.

Comment: We need transactionality. Consider this: we read, prune, write the whole document. If new entries were added between read and write, they would be lost. This can be solved either with transactions, or with series of updates, as I described.

Comment: If there was a write while you were building your transaction/batch, it will be retried automatically. But why do you want to perform multiple writes to the same document in there? Why not just perform a single write to that document, once you've calculated what it needs to become?

Comment: That's the point of the question. Transaction can be avoided (in this case) by doing multiple updates (not writes) to the document inside a batched write. What approach is better?

Comment: Added code for the two approaches for clarification. My guess is that avoiding the transaction is more performant, but it could be more costly.